# Nodejs unable to connect with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-modules, nodejs-server

I am creating a basic application to connect my Nodejs code to MongoDB but the code is not getting executed. Have attached image for the output I am getting. It is not printing to console

> got db connection

Have checked that the MongoDB is up and running and I am able to execute normal MongoDB operations using Mongo Client and Compass using mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017. Is there any missing configuration or any changes that need to be done on the code side.

- MongoDB version 5.0
- NodeJS version 18.13.0
- npm version 8.19.3

```js
var MongoC = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";
console.log('waiting db connection')
MongoC.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    //control not reaching here-- Expected to log to console 'got db connection'
    console.log('got db connection');
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('hello');
});
```

**Output:**
[image: Output it only displays 'Waiting db connection']

Comment: It might be helpful to add a link to the example within the official documentation that you are referencing, to ensure you are trying to implement the exact same thing.

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/index.html a similar example

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `await` keyword at the start of line #4. `MongoClient.connect` is an async function.

Example from documentation:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
// Connection URI
const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://sample-hostname:27017/?maxPoolSize=20&w=majority";
// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    await client.connect();
    // Establish and verify connection
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/connect/#std-label-node-connect-to-mongodb

Comment: This did not work. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Can you run the documentation example if you replace the url with your own?

Comment: The first example on http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/index.html is similar to the one I posted the question for but it also does not seem to work. Although I am able to connect with DB using the example at https://www.mongodb.com/developer/code-examples/javascript/node-connect-mongodb-3-3-2/ .

Answer (score 0):

1. Mongodb standard uri is:
   mongodb://MONGODB_USERNAME:MONGODB_PASSWORD@MONGODB_HOST:MONGODB_PORT
2. Did you save the file before running it? :))))
3. Use this:

```js
async function main(){
    /**
     * Connection URI. Update <username>, <password>, and <your-cluster-url> to reflect your cluster.
     * See https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/node/ for more details
     */
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<your-cluster-url>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
 

    const client = new MongoClient(uri);
 
    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
        await client.connect();
 
        // Make the appropriate DB calls
        await  listDatabases(client);
 
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: It gives this error 
ReferenceError: listDatabases is not defined

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/code-examples/javascript/node-connect-mongodb-3-3-2/ added listDatabases from here

Comment: You dont need to use listDatabases this is just an example. Check only your connection and sure your database service (Mongodb) be available. you can test with mongo compass.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing mongodb version in package.json to ^4.x.x and then npm install to install the required packages and their dependencies.